# Create a new iTunes column for "Play count/skip count ratio"?

Tags: itunes, music

Is it possible to somehow create a new column in iTunes for "Play count/skip count" ratio? I usually use Play Count as a way to determine what songs I like the most, but this typically excludes newer songs (unless I limit the playlist by date).

However, if I had a new column that took a song's play count and compared it to the song's skip count (such as 50 plays to 2 skips, 25:1; versus 20 plays and 5 skips, 4:1), then it'd be easier to see what songs I truly like, regardless of its age.

So, can this be done in iTunes at all, or is it absolutely not feasible?

Comment: robmathers is correct about the hard coding. However, I wrote a python script which creates playlists based on play/skip ratios as well as last played/skipped and date added. I can send it over to you if you'd like. If nothing else, you could use it for a good starting point for writing your own script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The columns and metadata that iTunes supports is hard coded unfortunately. There's no way to add a custom field or column to the browser.

You might be able to get a similar effect with some combination of smart playlists and/or some external scripting, but there's nothing built in that will do what you need.

Comment: Can u post the script here please...